# mongodb with java

Tags: mongodb, java-ee-6

I am trying to connect mongodb using java but i am getting following exception

```
Apr 3, 2013 10:55:41 AM com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse mapMappableContainerException 
SEVERE: The exception contained within MappableContainerException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/DB
at prime.task.TaskServices.save(TaskServices.java:49)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
```

If u anybody tell me how to solve this problem it will very helpful for me

Comment: do you have mongo-java-driver in your class path. looking like it's not there

Comment: I included mongo-java-driver-2.10.1.jar included using build path in eclipse. I am able to see all the classes in that location also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seams your IDE is not referring mongodb java driver correctly, please, try to use a different driver version, clear eclipse project, or create the project in a different workspace, or run the project manually on console add -cp command line param.

Regards,
Moacy